# Using data returned form Tally command in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a small piece of code to generate sequences, which is ok.

```
List = Reap[
    For[i = 1, i <= 10000, i++, 
      Sow[RandomSample[Join[Table["a", {2}], Table["b", {2}]],  2]]];][[2, 1]];
Tally[List]
```

Giving the following *output*,

```
{{{"b", "b"}, 166302}, {{"b", "a"}, 333668}, {{"a", "b"}, 332964}, {{"a", "a"}, 167066}}
```

My problem is I have yet to find a way  to extract the frequencies from the output ....?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What do you mean?  Surely the output shows the number of times each appears, presumably your "frequencies."  What do you want to do with this data?

Comment: Yes the output shows the frequency of each pair but I need to take the totals of each pair (a,b) etc and use them in plots/graphs etc, at the moment I have to manually enter "166302" etc when I need to plot which is slow and tedious...

Comment: I added an answer.  Is that what you want or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Generally do not start user-created Symbol names with a capital letter as these may conflict with internal functions.

It is not clear to me how you wish to transform the output.  One interpretation is that you just want:

```
{166302, 333668, 332964, 167066}
```

In your code you use `[[2, 1]]` so I presume you know how to use `Part`, of which this is a short form.  The documentation for `Part` includes:

> If any of the list<sub>i</sub> are `All` or `;;`, all parts at that level are kept.

You could therefore use:

```
Tally[list][[All, 2]]
```

You could also use:

```
Last /@ Tally[list]
```

---

As [george](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004168/george) comments you can use `Sort`, which due to the structure of the `Tally` data will sort first by the item because it appears first in each list, and each list has the same length.

```
tally = 
 {{{"b","b"},166302},{{"b","a"},333668},{{"a","b"},332964},{{"a","a"},167066}};

Sort[tally][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {167066, 332964, 333668, 166302}
> ```

You could also convert your data into a list of `Rule` objects and then pull values from a predetermined list:

```
rules = Rule @@@ tally
```

> ```
> {{"b", "b"} -> 166302, {"b", "a"} -> 333668, {"a", "b"} -> 332964, {"a", "a"} -> 167066}
> ```

These could be in any order you choose:

```
{{"a", "a"}, {"a", "b"}, {"b", "a"}, {"b", "b"}} /. rules
```

> ```
> {167066, 332964, 333668, 166302}
> ```

Merely to illustrate another technique if you have a specific list of items you wish to count you may find value in this `Sow` and `Reap` construct.  For example, with a random list of `"a", "b", "c", "d"`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat = RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 50];
```

Counting the `"a"` and `"c"` elements:

```
Reap[Sow[1, dat], {"a", "c"}, Tr[#2] &][[2, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {19, 5}
> ```

This is not as fast as `Tally` but it is faster than doing a `Count` for each element, and sometimes the syntax is useful.

Comment: That works,I can use the data in the plots Thank you! Is it possible to arrange that list of four numbers returned by your commands in a particular order? eg {number of AA's, number of BB's AB's BA's}. The reason I ask this as each time I run the code it changes the order of the output..

Comment: Sort@Tally will give you a consistent order.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard and George for your help, I really appreciate it. I can now generate the graphs without having to input the values manually, and the labels match up on the graphs..thanks again this will save me a lot of time..